# What do I do if someone studied the same topic before, but did so inadequately?

Tags: phd, research-process, thesis

I am planning to research on topic for masters by research course. Googling, I found that a "micro-research" study on a similar topic (some objectives matching) has been done by somebody as a part of coursework master’s thesis (project) work. But there is nothing online except some initial pages of thesis (as a blog post on the student's website), so I am unable to read the whole thesis and understand  what has been done. It has not been published in a peer-reviewed forum, and it looks like it was done in around 4 months with a small sample size for coursework thesis. Moreover, it seems to be in a different field of study.

From the available pages it looks like research has tried to touch most of the things but at a very superficial level: three pages of data analysis and one page of findings also make me question how in-depth the analysis was.

I am writing a research proposal and really confused how I should include it. Especially in previous works, do I need to validate or justify each of my objectives against its objectives? (or show the difference)

I am thinking of expanding the scope, objectives of research and planning to use different data analysis methods. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to contact the **author(s)** of that coursework master’s thesis (project) work?

Comment: Yes but the problem is not only getting the thesis's missing pages but also quality of the work that has been done. Table of contents is available and first and final chapter(around 20 content pages out of total 64 pages are available as blog post). Some objectives seem to be matching. Now do I start writing how my research is going to be different(on scope,process,addressing shortcomings) in proposal based on that?

Comment: In  my opinion, you should get the full paper(thesis) and then assess its value and determine how to reference (use) it.

Comment: Thanks but I have doubt on its value that's why i am asking this question. I agree on all its point obviously,another research on same or similar topic would not have been necessary. The two researches will be totally different on scale,methods,efforts,time frame but problem is on objectives it looks similar. So,that's the problem. Rather than trying to extend that study I am trying to look things from new angle and in more depth.

Comment: _problem is on objectives it looks similar_. I am afraid you will need to reference that paper when you write yours. This is my opinion, though

Comment: From your description, I understand that the thesis (fragment) essentially looks into something you want to look into yourself, but you feel it does so in an inadequately small scale. Is it an option to simply call things by their name then and point out that results from a small-scale study in a thesis *suggest* -whatever you hope to find-, and you would like to investigate into the same direction, but much more thoroughly, using additional techniques of evaluation, etc.? But like that, the existence of that master thesis might even be beneficial for you, as a first "proof of concept".

Comment: The obvious choose would be to reference this paper ("Johnson, J. (2014) 'bla bla bla', unpublished thesis, University of What Ever, http://blog access date: april 8th 2015" Reference software such as Endnote have an unpublished manuscript category) in the literature review part of your thesis.

Comment: @Mapper Spot on.Thanks for suggestions. Well research is on "specific issues of specific industry in specific country' or kind of case study of a country.Now my proposal already includes detail literature review of around 9 Phd studies on that industry and on that issue(2.5 pages).If i refute that thesis I may have to devote another page for it. I started it but the paper seems to have many problems or is not qualitative(even doesn't have proper referencing for vital claims),so I  am in dilemma either I should  do it or not. My proposal is already 10 pages so don't want to make it too long.

Comment: @Maarten Thanks.Well can i call it 'unpublished'? or is there any other better terms? . The proposal was never meant to be published i guess reading at its abstract.Rather it was just trying to fulfill the partial requirement of a subject or coursework master's degree and just submitted to College. The research mentions that analysis is not in depth as thesis has to be submitted by 4 months as degree requirement.

Comment: You should keep in mind the  possibility  that the author of the thesis you found is continuing to work on the subject, possibly improving the deficiencies you noted. This would be another very good reason to contact them and try to learn the current state of their work - if your proposed work closely matches what they are doing now, you are at risk of being scooped.

Comment: I agree with @scaaahu that you need to get the paper (if you can) and evaluate it. After that, you should discuss this with your adviser.

Answer (score 1):

> But there is nothing online except some initial pages of thesis (as a blog post on the student's website [...]. It has not been published in a peer-reviewed forum, and it looks like it was done in around 4 months with a small sample size for coursework thesis. Moreover, it seems to be in a different field of study.
>
> From the available pages it looks like research has tried to touch most of the things but at a very superficial level: three pages of data analysis and one page of findings also make me question how in-depth the analysis was.

None of this indicates that the previous study was 'inadequate'!

You should definitly mention this study in your proposal, but use better arguments than 'three pages of data analysis and one page of findings' to describe its limitations!

Comment: Yup. Thanks and that is what i did.I listed limitations of that research and were around 1 page long.I am trying to make it bit shorter(just really difficult). No references for data-stats-many claims,data analysis and findings all based on just mean,mode analysis to name few.Any ways thanks I have included it. It just looks like it was done for the thesis requirement of the course.